# Getting Min and Max from Array using php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am facing an issue getting my desired value from an array, in PHP

Look at my array

```
 array(

  "0"=>array("id"=>"255","price"=>"2","discount"=>"1"),
  "1"=>array("id"=>"256","price"=>"2","discount"=>"3"),
  "2"=>array("id"=>"257","price"=>"2","discount"=>"4"),
  "3"=>array("id"=>"255","price"=>"3","discount"=>"5")

 );
```

I need Min Price and Max Discount, this time, I need array ID 2, that is

`"2"=>array("id"=>"257","price"=>"2","discount"=>"4"),`

Because in this array price is lower 2, and discount is 4, on next record you can see discount is much higher that is 5, but price is 3 which is higher then 2, so Desired result is sub array id 2

Kindly let me know How can i do this ?

Comment: If you sort the array by the price ascending and the discount descending, then the resultant array will be in the order your after( i.e. `array_multisort(array_column($data, "price"), SORT_ASC, 
    array_column($data, "discount"), SORT_DESC, $data  );`).  Then use element `[0]` of that array for the item your after.

Comment: Also if this is the result of a SQL query - you can add an ORDER BY clause similar to the sort above which should give you the same result (but without the SQL it's difficult to know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this solution

```php
$array = array(
    "0" => array("id" => "255", "price" => "2", "discount" => "1"),
    "1" => array("id" => "256", "price" => "2", "discount" => "2"),
    "2" => array("id" => "257", "price" => "2", "discount" => "4"),
    "3" => array("id" => "255", "price" => "3", "discount" => "5"),
);

$minPrice = min(array_column($array, 'price'));
$maxDiscountIndex = $maxDiscount = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['price'] == $minPrice && $maxDiscount < (int) $value['discount']) {
        $maxDiscountIndex = $key;
        $maxDiscount = $value['discount'];
    }
}

echo $maxDiscountIndex; // 2
```

Algorithm description:

- Find the minimum price in all array
- Loop through all minimum price elements and find the maximum discount value